# How to access a web component located inside a child component

Tags: angular, parent-child, web-component

The parent component include this on its template:

```
<six-drawer label="Notificaciones" class="notifications">
 <mur-notification-dialog (newEmision)="listenNewEmision($event)"></mur-notification-dialog>
 <six-button slot="footer" class="open-all-notifications-button" (click)="openNotifications()">
  Ver todas las notificaciones
 </six-button>
</six-drawer>
```

From parent component I need to check if six-drawer property open is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a local reference to `six-drawer` in the template HTML and handle the `open` property like the following:

```js
@Component({...})
export class SixDrawerComponent {
   open = false;
   isValid!: boolean;

   makeItValid(): void {
      this.isValid = true;
   }
}
```

```html
<six-drawer #sixDrawer label="Notificaciones" class="notifications">
  ...
  <p>is six drawer open? {{ sixDrawer.open }}</p>
  <p>is six drawer valid? {{ sixDrawer.isValid }}</p>

  <button (click)="sixDrawer.makeItValid()">Make it valid</button>
</six-drawer>
```

Also, you could use `ViewChild` in order to handle the child programmatically like the following:

```html
<six-drawer #sixDrawer label="Notificaciones" class="notifications">
</six-drawer>
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('sixDrawer') sixDrawer!: SixDrawerComponent;

  someEvent(): void {
    const isOpen = this.sixDrawer.open; 
    // and then access the rest of the child component
  }
}
```